# How can I show my stock on currency.poe.trade?

Tags: path-of-exile

After some time spent flipping currency I noticed that some players have their stock shown on [currency.poe.trade](http://currency.poe.trade/) while for others it doesn't appear.

This is how it looks on the website.
[image]

The little "api" tag next to the "online" tag tells me that this is somehow achievable through the in-game premium stash tab API but I haven't figured out how this works.

For the normal poe.trade website every item is listed as soon as the stash tab is public, however on the currency my stock doesn't show, even though I have my currency stash tab listed as public.

Do I have to set a special note? I know that the price can be determined with a certain note on a (currency) item, but does this help with showing the stock and can I still use the web-based buyout/sell options when my items are listed via note?

I'm trying to lower the amount of people spamming me when I ran out of a certain currency while flipping but I still want to be able to use the trading tools on the website.

Comment: Also as a clarification: while they are 3rd party websites, both poe.trade and currency.poe.trade are tools heavily used by the community (maybe even necessary unless playing in the solo-self-found league) and could be considered as part of the game. They are also based on the stash-tab API from in game.

Comment: I can confirm this, currency.poe.trade and poe.trade is something that even the creators of the game use themselves. It's just as much part of the game as the real money auction house was on diablo 3.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud well I wouldn't compare it to the D3 auction house. The two websites are solely built for in-game currency trading. Any real money trades are still prohibited.

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to back you up and say that it's an integral part of the game and doesn't fall under the "recommendation" close option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "api" icon means that the data has been retrieved using [the public API](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Public_stash_tab_API) rather than by scraping the forums or other sources.

Yes, you need premium stash tabs to make use of them.

Once one of your tabs is a premium one, put in there the currency you'd like to sell, set the tab to public, right click on the currency (only on 1 stack per type is enough) and select the price of the single orb. Now all the currency that you have in that stash tab will be seen through the api as "stock".

> Let's say I want to trade my chaos orbs for alchemy, vaal and exalteds. Do I have to create 3 stacks? Also can I keep those in a separate (normal) premium tab?

Using a normal stash tab (i.e. NOT the currency special stash tab), yes, it is possible. Make 3 stacks, price each accordingly (alch/vaal/ex) and all three listings will appear on currency.poe.trade

A word of warning: the moment you remove the last chaos from the stack associated with, let's say, the vaal price, that price will be removed from the api. The best thing you can do is to have 3 chaoses sitting in 3 separate stacks that you never touch. Unpriced stacks will count towards the "stock" number.

Comment: Yeah I thought this was the case also. As long as you have premium stash tabs and they're public, it's kind of automatic.

Comment: Can I make multiple stacks of the same currency for different prices (especially in different tabs)? Let's say I want to trade my chaos orbs for alchemy, vaal and exalteds. Do I have to create 3 stacks? Also can I keep those in a separate (normal) premium tab? I'm currently using a currency stash tab and I don't see how I would be able to create multiple stacks of the same currency in there.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud I actually have all my premium stash tabs listed as public but it doesn't show up... Then again I'm using the buying/selling interface of the website.

Comment: @Jutschge edited to answer your comment.